# shuffle(rearrange randomly) the randomly generated password

Tags: java, random, passwords

I am generating a random password. My password is 8 characters in length and it includes the special characters. I need to keep the `first letter as alphabet` and need to shuffle the remaining seven characters so that it will be a `mixture of alphanumeric + ascii characters`.

```
public String generatePassword() {
        int passwordLength = MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
        StringBuffer password = new StringBuffer(passwordLength);
        //first character as an alphabet
        password.append(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1)).toString();
        String alphaNumeric = RandomStringUtils.random(5, true, true);
        String asciiChars = RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(2);
        password.append(alphaNumeric).append(asciiChars);
        return password.toString();
    }
```

I need some help to shuffle the last 7 characters. How to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to shuffle them if they are already random?

Comment: `Collections.shuffle` is what you need

Comment: Randomising/shuffling a random sequence doesn't do anything, it won't make it more random.

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for suggesting me to use StringBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Collections API has an inbuilt shuffle method that you can use: see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).
Basically, you need to create a `List` from the last 7 characters, and pass it to `Collections.shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that strict requirements, then you could append the char randomly:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   if (random.nextBoolean()) {
       password.append(RandomStringUtils.random(1, true, true));
   } else {
       password.append(RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(1));
   }
}
```

If you need a guarantee, that there's at least one of each kind, then you could add a simple test:

```
boolean hasAlphaNumeric = false;
boolean hasAscii = false;
while (hasAlphaNumeric == false || hasAscii == false) {
  Random random = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
      password.append(RandomStringUtils.random(1, true, true));
      hasAlphaNumeric = true;
    } else {
      password.append(RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(1));
      hasAscii = true;
    }
  }
}
```